# Copy, Insert and Update

Tags: t-sql

I have inserted 9000 rows into the AcctHist table in the database. The LedgerID is 'HOME'. Now I need to copy these rows and insert them again into the same table, but with LedgedID = 'FIELD' (LedgerID is part of the Primary key). No other changes.

How can I achieve this ? Do I need to copy this data to excel, make the changes and then insert again?

Comment: Are there any other rows in `AccHist` with a `LedgerID = 'HOME`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I inserted. Now I have to copy all these rows with ledgerId = 'HOME' and insert it again into the same table, but with ledgerID ='FIELD'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that all rows with LedgerID = 'HOME' are the ones you inserted and the ones you need copied, this should work, swapping out `<all other columns in AcctHist, comma delimited>` with your actual column names.  Note that if you have any identity fields, you should omit those, since they will be populated automatically.

```
INSERT INTO AcctHist
(
    LedgerID, 
    <all other columns in AcctHist, comma delimited>
)
SELECT 
    'FIELD', 
    <all other columns in AcctHist, comma delimited>
FROM AcctHist WHERE LedgerID = 'HOME'
```